# How to dynamically populate a custom ribbon edit box

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have a cell with the formula that counts the number of times today's date occurs in a column. `=COUNTIF(H1:H21,TODAY())`. Naturally this number changes daily.
![SheetView]{https://www.flickr.com/photos/debbieheaney/49037908717/in/dateposted-public/)![SheetView]
The button next to it the screenshot fills in today's date.
For a charity I volunteer at they have a spreadsheet whereby the column runs to over 600.
I want to move that number from the bottom of the spreadsheet to the ribbon so as to avoid the long scroll to the bottom/the jumping back and forward.

This is for Microsoft Office Excel 2013. I've tried many examples from all over the internet but I just can't find exactly what I'm looking for and I can't figure things out.

the Ribbon XML

```xml
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
onLoad="OnRibbonLoad">
<ribbon>    
            <tab id="tabDailyNumbers" label="Daily Count">
                <group id="grpDailyNumbers" label="Daily Numbers">
                <editBox id="NetFigureText" label="Uses Today" getText="onGetText" />
                <separator id="separatorone" />
                <button id="btnDateToday" label="Todays Date" size="large" onAction="subTodaysDate" />
                </group>
        </tab>
```

The VBA

```vb
'Get a global referance to the ribbon object when the ribbon loads
Public Sub onRibbonLoad(ByVal ribbon As IRibbonUI)

Set globalRibbon = ribbon
    Public Sub onGetText(Control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Text)

'Callback for NetFigureText getText

Text = NetFigure

End Sub

Public Sub NetFigureGrab(Control As IRibbonControl)

'Retrieves data - in this case I will set data to be a static value as 
just complicates the example
NetFigure = "0"

MyRibbon.InvalidateControl "NetFigureText"

End Sub

'Callback for btnDateToday onAction
Sub subTodaysDate(Control As IRibbonControl)

With Selection
    .Value = Date
End With

End Sub
```

I can manage static values no problem but I can't get the editbox to change dynamically. I'm not even getting error messages that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: That link doesn't work?
Try this one:- https://www.flickr.com/photos/debbieheaney/49037908717/

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an editbox with a callback function named 'onGetText' but you have no method in the code you provide called onGetText.  You need code along these lines

```
Public Sub onGetText(byref Control as IRibbonControl, byref ReturnValue as variant)

    Select case Control.Id

        case "NetFigureText"

            returnValue =cvar(<GetExcelValueThatYouWantInTheTextBox>)
            globalRibbon.InvalidateCOntrol Control.id

        Case "Other OnGetCallback"

             ' Do action for other callback
        case else

         debug.print "Unknown Control.Id: " & Control.id

    end select
End sub
```

Comment: ater a short break for something to eat I came back and tried your example Freeflow.
The custom editbox is blank, not even the default of "0" is there.
I've been at this a while and it might well be time to give take a big break from it.

I did get things working but I probably did it the long way around?
Will try again another day.

Thank you for your help and assistance in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

I knew that would do the trick.
Ask for help and whilst you're waiting you solve the problem yourself.

I was forgetting to invalidate the editbox.

the VBA now reads as:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Call RibEditBox

End Sub
```

and

```
Public Sub RibEditBox()

NetFigure = Range("TodaysUses").Value

globalRibbon.InvalidateControl ("NetFigureText")

End Sub
```